# Is every material able to exist in every state of matter?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, physical-chemistry

I was shocked while reading Kittel's "Introduction to Solid State Physics", that the solid state of noble gases is a well described and makes one of the fundamental achievements of solid state physics.

So I wonder: is every possible element and every possible compound able to exist in any of the 3 states of matter?

Comment: 7 states of matter, see [here](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080725095433AAFTPF5)

Comment: Spin-polarized atomic hydrogen (a collection of hydrogen atoms in a strong magnetic field) stays gaseous down to absolute zero temperatures.

Comment: Yes, well I always had a problem with the classifications of states of matter involving plasma, quark-gluon plasma etc. I believe you can usually safely keep them out of the picture, since their emergence comes in very specific problems. I mean it's not like we will miss an important characteristic of metals not mentioning the quark-gluon plasma state, as it is an obvious property of all hadronic matter and at the same time not a subject of your typical thermodynamical speculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every element can exist in the 3 basic states: gas, liquid, solid. It is just a matter of enough freezing and high pressure (to solidify gases, even Helium) or enough heat and low pressure (to vaporize metals, even tungsten). At even higher temperatures the gas can ionize, which can be considered a 4th state of matter.

Some chemical compounds (like water, alcohol, carbon dioxide) can also exist in the 3 basic matter states. But most large molecules simply decompose under higher temperature, so they don't have a boiling point and don't exist as gas. The example is the DNA, various hormones (like insulin), etc.

Your question title contains the word "materials", so I would add that for a general material (which is a mixture of various compounds and elements) the 3 states of matter are also sometimes not achievable. For example wood cannot be in gaseous state, because the structure that makes a wood a wood woud decompose.

Comment: "Every element can exist in the 3 basic states". What about the structure of the molecules in 3 different states? Do they have to be the same? I mean can nitrogen be just nitrogen atoms at solid state then diatomic molecule in liquid state?

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas Solids can be in different crystal structures, it is called polymorphism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(materials_science)

Answer (score 1):

Logically yes,, since anything consisting of atoms shall have vanderwaals forces atleast by virtue of temporary fluctuations of electron cloud and theoretically we can surely reduce the temperature sufficiently so as the average KE is less than vander waals stablising energy,, ( i ignored gravity which is too weak in usual cases)